# Running Spring boot with Opencv on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, opencv, tomcat, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Spring boot application packaged as WAR which uses OpenCV for some image processing and I would like to run it on Elastic Beanstalk (Tomcat environment). Is there a way how to package it with the native Opencv libraries?

Everything is working fine on my local machine where I have the following configuration:

- Tomcat 8 running inside Eclipse with my application deployed to it.
- Opencv 3.1 installed on my computer
- `opencv_310.jar` placed in `src/webapp/WEB-INF/lib`
- Opencv added to Java build path (`path/to/opencv/build/bin`)
- Tomcat running with VM argument `-Djava.library.path=path/to/opencv/opencv/build/lib`

This setup works fine and I am even able to package it with `maven clean pakcage`.

However, if I want to deploy to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk, I just cannot assume that Opencv will be installed on that machine (it won't) so I need to somehow package it inside my WAR file so everything is self-contained.

When I deploy my WAR to ELB, I always get

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java300 in java.library.path
```

when loading Opencv with  `System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);`

I found some tutorials on this for [archaic versions](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nu.pattern/opencv/2.4.9-4) of Opencv but I cannot seem to figure out how to do this easily. I would be glad for any tips, because I have been stuck on this for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using this excellent [Github project](https://github.com/PatternConsulting/opencv) which provides OpenCV Java bindings packaged with native libraries and provided as a Maven dependency.

There is also a newer [fork](https://github.com/openpnp/opencv) of this project with more up-to-date version of OpenCV which I am probably going to switch to. It supports OpenCV 2.4.10 which is a step back from version 3.1 that I was using but it does everything I expected from it.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your tomcat server, you could pass the path to native libraries, so they will be preloaded, like this:

```
java -Djava.library.path=...
```

other way would be to put the libraries into the folder where the main jar (jar that you run tomcat from) of tomcat is.

Comment: I am doing that on localhost when my libraries are installed on my machine. Could you provide an example setup how to do it on elastic beanstalk without opencv installed (where to put the native library in the war file and how to reference it). I can;t seem to get this step right...

Comment: You shouldn't put the native libraries into war (if you're not using some library to extract them and load dynamically, for instance with birdJ) You could pass them as argument to the VM on which the tomcat runs, or you could put them into the same folder where is the jar running tomcat.

Comment: But is there a way how to package and deploy the application so it is not dependent on native libraries? I am not sure how to handle this on ELB...

Comment: How would you like to use code using native libraries without native libraries? You could use birdJ to extract and load proper libraries for each platform in runtime, it is a project that simplifies the loading of proper libraries on each platform.

Comment: I'm not sure if Amazon allow use of native libraries in your app... you need to check that first.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to extract the native libraries into ELB and use them automatically through java without the need of installing OpenCV first.